# Why does if(dynamic && string) compile?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Can anybody please explain to me why the following expression can be compiled:

```
dynamic dynValue = 42;
string strValue = "TestVal";
if(dynValue && strValue)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I know that the compiler basically ignores anything that has to do with dynamic, but shouldn't it throw an error for the `string` part?

Comment: I know, that's how I found out about this, but I feel like this should throw an error at compile time since you are trying to evaluate `&& string`

Comment: `dynValue` can appear to be *any type* (e.g. `class` with `&&` operator which accepts `string` argument) that's why the system performs check in run time

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for the clarification! Now I understand :)

Comment: See also Eric Lippert's recent [puzzle](https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/14/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle/) (and [solution](https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/)) for a very similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental rule of `dynamic` is: the behaviour of the program at runtime is the same as the behaviour of a program where `dynamic` was replaced with the runtime type of the object at compile time.

Since there are types which, at compile time, would allow `x && someString`, if the type of `x` were known, then it must also be legal for `x` to be `dynamic`.

If at runtime it turns out that `x` is *not* of a type that allows `&&` with a string, then that will be a runtime error.

More generally: **`dynamic` turns off the compile-time type safety system**.  Your question is "why do I not get type errors when I turn off the type error detection system?"  The question answers itself when you ask it that way. If you want type errors then **do not turn off the type error detection system**.